# Wrong fragment is loading when I am trying to load new one

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I am trying to load a new fragment it loads previous fragment.
I have a fragment profile fragment and on it some onclicks are there. I want to open a new fragment on the click event but it is opening the previous fragment, somewhere backstack is missing or something else i could not find out.

```
        relativeLayoutManagement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction;
                if(getParentFragment() == null){
                    transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                }else {
                    transaction = childFragmentManagerOfParent.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutChildContainer, HotelManagementFragment.newInstance(),FragmentTags.HOTEL_MANAGEMENT);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(FragmentTags.HOTEL_MANAGEMENT);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my new fragment code.

```
public class HotelManagementFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public HotelManagementFragment() {

    }

    public static HotelManagementFragment newInstance() {
        HotelManagementFragment fragment = new HotelManagementFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hotel_managment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: post only **needed** code not a whole class

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load fragment on another fragment then Use that id which is in your main activity layout like this. //transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity_fragment_id,your_fragment);

Comment: I got the culprit in my code, actually it was the layout xml problem something weird was there I have replaced the layout xml then now it is working.